# Is it possible to use a parameter from a vs studio project in a c# code

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio

I wanted to know if it is possible to use a int parameter from a vs studio project in my c# code.

Here's some screenshot to make this clearer:

[image: Vs Stud Parameters]

I would like to use "periodeconges" from the xml, so I can modify only the xml without touching the code to change the value.

Here's the part where I want to call "periodeconges":

[image: C# calling periodeconges]

It says me that the var doesnt exist in the current context.Is there any way to access to the var from the xml ?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Where do the parameters come from ? app.config ? user.config ? Something else ?

Comment: Try Properties.Settings.Default.periodchanges.

Comment: @Cid Parameters are from app.config

Comment: @Cid I will try the method in this post, thanks for your help :) .